# Hibernate database mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

Firstly, I am somewhat new with Hibernate.  To get to know the technology I am using it in a project.  I am trying to map the following database:

```
Campaign
  campaignId(+)
  name

Promotion
  campaignId(+)
  discount(+)
  product
  message
```

I've indicated the primary key in both cases with a (+).  The 'campaignId' in Promotion is a foreign key to Campaign to model the 1:m mapping (A Campaign has many Promotions).  Using annotations I am stuck on how to do this.

I do not really want to add a promotionId in the Promotion table as it makes working with the data cumbersome.  This of course, makes the bridging table a bit tricky.  I also have problems working with a foreign key that is also part of the primary key.

Is a mapping for this possible at all?

---

Ok, I got it working.  Sort of.  Have to check if persistence actually work.  I did the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAMPAIGNS")
@Audited
public class CampaignEntity {
    private int campaignId;
    private String name;
    private List<PromotionEntity> promotions;

    public CampaignEntity(int campaignId, String name) {
        this.campaignId = campaignId;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cmp_id")
    public int getCampaignId() {
        return campaignId;
    }

    public void setCampaignId(int campaignId) {
        this.campaignId = campaignId;
    }

    // Campaign name here... left out to save space

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "cmp_id")
    public List<PromotionEntity> getPromotions() {
        return promotions;
    }

    public void setPromotions(List<PromotionEntity> promotions) {
        this.promotions = promotions;
    }
}
```

Promotion is a vanilla mapping (not using embedded after all), with the fields: campaignId, discount, message. (It also does not have a @ManyToOne annotation.)

Does that make sense?

Lastly, and this will be first prize: as you can see I'm using Envers to audit the whole thing.  The above creates a rather ugly "CampaignEntity_PromotionEntity_AUD" table.  I understand that it is needed, but how can I rename it to CAMPAIGN_PROMOTION_AUD rather?

Thanks guys!

---

I got an answer on a lonely website deeply hidden away in far-corners of the Hibernate's Jira error tracking website: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-3729.

The answer is to use @AuditJoinTable(name = "CAMPAIGN_PROMOTION_AUD") of course.

Comment: Do you mean perhaps that you don't want promotionId in the *Campaign* table? I'm not sure how that makes sense.

Comment: Correct, the campaign id should be in the Promotion table as a single column (cmp_id), which is also part of the Promotion's primary key. (see above.)  I think I have it with the edited solution above, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I am now using.  It works well and Hibernate handles the PKs of the Promotions for me.  Thanks again.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CAMPAIGNS")
@Audited
public class CampaignEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer campaignId;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String campaignName;

     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
     @JoinTable(name = "CAMPAIGN_PROMOTIONS", 
                joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "campaign_id") }, 
                inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "promotion_id") })
     private Set<PromotionEntity> promotions;

     ...
}
```

and then, PromotionEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PROMOTIONS")
@Audited
public class PromotionEntity implements Comparable<PromotionEntity> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "discount", nullable = false)
    private Integer discount;

    @Column(name = "message", nullable = false)
    private String message;

    ...
}
```

I also prefer annotating the fields rather than the getters as it is more compact and reads easier.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic example of a one-to-many relationship and its inverse.

```
public class Campaign
{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "campaign)
    private List<Promotion> promotions;
}

public class Promotion
{
    @ManyToOne
    private Campaign campaign;
}
```

Comment: This does not quite work... the "Campaign campaign" entry makes it difficult to define it as part of Promotion's primary key.  I need "campaign_id" to be the foreign key in this table, while also being part of Promotion's primary key.  A "campaign id" together with "discount" defines the entity uniquely.

Comment: Why does it need to be part of the primary key? Just use a non-business PK (i.e. an "id" field) and define your business keys as (unique) indexes.

Comment: When a campaign is updated from the front-end, I receive a Campaign with a set of Promotions (containing discount, product and message).  I now have to write a query to find all the Promotions' PKs, simply to update the Campaign. (Remember, I do not have the PK available from the collection.)  That sounds awfully wrong to me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Are you worried that hibernate will fetch data that you do not need?

Comment: Hi Wouter... I got it sorted.  You are quite correct.  Simply clearing the the set in the Campaign and populating it with the new (and modified) Promotion objects worked beautifully. As a Hibernate new-comer I am still reluctant to let Hiberante handle all of the "details".  My thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `EmbeddedId` to create a multi-field PK.

- Remove the PK fields from `Promotion`
- Create a separate entity, say `PromotionPK`, without any annotations except for `@Column` on the PK fields
- In `Promotion`, include that PK class as field, annotating it using `@EmbeddedId`, with getters and setters

The FK mapping is as Wouter indicated.

Comment: Do you mind giving a short example?  I do not know how to map the @ManyToOne annotation using this composite key... where does that go? In the composite key or in the Promotion class?