# How can Hibernate map this?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm still struggling with this:

[Hibernate database mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873413/hibernate-database-mapping)

Sorry for rephrasing and reposting...

The ideas I had simply do not work once I try to implement them.  The biggest problem is the PK/FK fields that seems to be incompatible.  Here's the two tables I have in mind:

```
Campaign
  PK Long   campaignId
     String description

Promotion
  PK Long   campaignId (FK to Campaign)
  PK Long   discount   (unique set of discounts for the campaign)
     String messgge
```

(Each campaign has many promotions)

The problem is that a Promotion cannot exist without a Campaign object.  It is very tedious to work with promotionIds.  What I really need is to have single Campaign object in the Object-model where I simply access the set of Promotions associated with it.  Each promotion simply has a discount and a message associated with it.  Something like the following:

```
class Campaign {
  Long campaignId;
  String description;
  Set<Promotion> promotions;

  // constructors, getters, setters
}

class Promotion {
  int discount;
  String message;

  // constructors, getters, setters
}
```

Is this at all possible?  How can I map this using Hibernate using standard JPA annotations? I do not care that much about the table-mappings any more as long as I can have the Object-model described above.

Please... :(

---

**EDIT**

I got this working using an @ElementCollection on the Promotion side and changing Promotion from @Entity to @Embeddable.  This works well and is exactly what I need.  However, now the auditing breaks as Envers refuse to work with Lists.

I know that campaignId and discount in the Promotion table is unique, but how do I tell Envers that?

Comment: You have PK Long   discount in your table and int discount; in your class, which is correct? To be more precise: what does discount mean - is it ID of promotion or reference to another table or is it some value like discount in percents?

Comment: Thank you for asking. Each campaign (with unique campaignId) offers a number of Promotions with different discounts. (For example campaign 1, could offer promotions of 10%, 25% and 66%).  A Promotion cannot exist without a Campaign.  Therefore, in the table Promotion, the combination of campaignId and discount will be unique (i.e. another campaign may offer the same set of discounts... but possibly with a different message for each). See the tables that I have at the top. Does this make better sense?

Answer (score 0):

In `Campaign` class you can map the set of `Promotion`s in the simplest case using:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "promotions")
public Set<Promotoion> getPromotions() {
  return promotions;
}
```

On how to use `@OneToMany` please refer to [1](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html) or [2](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/OneToMany).

Comment: Is this in any way possible with an @ElementCollection?  The problem with a standard mapping is that I need to work with PKs in the Promotion class.  If I create a new set of promotions for an existing Campaign, the old ones do not get replaced.  All I need is to add and remove a new collection of promotions as if it is a normal field.

Comment: In fact it is... but it breaks Auditing... see EDIT in original question.